# Tool for username analysis

Tags: open-source, python, data-analysis, language

I am looking for a tool to analyse/compare user names.
Let's say I have given list of usernames:

```
alex_01
mitchel1971
mike__
...
```

I'd expect the tool to compare those usernames and output something like this:

```
100% contain human names
100% contain english names
67% contain numbers
33% contain birthdays
33% contain "-"
```

Is there a free tool, preferably in python, that can achieve something like this?